# How to uncomment everything between 2 lines of a file?

Tags: python, text-files

Basically i have a text file which where all lines start with "//".  I need to somehow remove the "//" between(and including) lines that start(and end) with a specific string;

example :

```
//text
//more text
//DELIMITER_START
//some code
//DELIMITER_END 
//more text
```

And the output should be

```
//text
//more text
  DELIMITER_START  (this looks like #ifdef 'something')
  some code
  DELIMITER_END    (this looks like #endif 'something')
//more text
```

i tried to use string splitting, but somehow it uncomments only the first occurence  of #ifdef and the line following it and then stops;

this is my code

```
with open(out_file, 'w') as output_file:
    for line in lines:
        if DELIMITER_START in line:
            start = lines.index(line)
            lines[lines.index(line)] = line[2:]
            current_index = start + 1
            while DELIMITER_END not in lines[current_index]:
                if lines[current_index].startswith('//'):
                    lines[current_index] = lines[current_index][2:]
                    current_index = current_index + 1
                    lines[current_index] = lines[current_index][2:]
                    output_file.write(''.join(lines))
```

Comment: Regex is probably not necessary here, just basic string operations. What did you try so far?

Comment: forgot to add my code; Edited now

Answer (score 1):

You could use a flag to switch the uncommenting mode.

Something along these lines (using lists here but you can easily adapt to write to file):

```
text = '''//text
//more text
//DELIMITER_START
//some code
//DELIMITER_END 
//more text'''

lines = text.split('\n')
out = []
uncomment = False
for line in lines:
    if line[2:].startswith('DELIMITER_START'):
        uncomment = True
    if uncomment:
        line = '  '+line[2:]
    if line[2:].startswith('DELIMITER_END'):
        uncomment = False
    out.append(line)
```

output:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(out))
//text
//more text
  DELIMITER_START
  some code
  DELIMITER_END 
//more text
```